# I am not able to see the active questions selected by tag

Tags: support

About two weeks ago, I am unable to list the active questions selected by chosen tag. For example, I am at main page:

[image: stackA]

where active questions are listed. Then I click to `{tables}` (for instance) and I get:

[image: stackB]

But I need to see the active questions from the selected tag no this message.

IMHO, I am not in Featured tab. I don't understand this. I tried to remove all my web-browser configuration and started with new login to the sx.com. Without effect.

I noticed that this is user dependent problem at server side. When I am not logged (i.e anonymous user) then all is OK. Only when I am logged as wipet then I have problems described above. I use Chromium 11.0.696.57 or 
Mozilla Firefox 37.0.2 at two different computers and with the same problem. It means that it is not client-side problem, it is only wipet-side problem :(.

May be I did something wrong in my personal configuration, but I don't remember that I did something with it. I am not familiar with such graphical level of abstraction, sorry.

Comment: What happens when you click on "Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?" Or just select a different tab to start with. Does that perhaps change your default selection for future usage?

Comment: @Werner The text "Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?" is not clickable, so nothing happens. And I totally don't understand what does mean "select a different tab to start with". Where? How to select? What?

Comment: Click on "newest", or "votes", or... those are the "tabs".

Comment: @Werner Aha, the words "info", "newest" etc. at the mentioned page are clickable. Now I see the actual questions as before, thanks. As I said: I am totally lost at this level of graphics abstraction. I don't know what happened. If there isn't a UNIX command line and well structured text configuration files, then I am unable to use a computer. Sorry for my question.

Comment: That's not a problem. Let's see if the problem persists. If, upon login or usage in the next week or so, the problem is still there (that it constantly reverts back to a "featured" tab that doesn't exist), then it's a different bug. Otherwise, this might just be a one-time problem that is corrected by switching to a visible tab.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was between the keyboard and the chair, of course. I vaguely remember that I did select a tag-related page and I did click to the "featured tab" because a noticable and interesting blue number was presented here. Then I leaved this page and I forgot about this. Many days after, I tried to look to the actual questions selected by a tag and, Houston, we have a problem. Of course, there is typically none featured questions at tag-related pages.

I meant that the words "info", "newest", "frequent" are inactive because they are in grey color. And I meant that the tab type ("active" in main page) is inherited to the tag-selected pages. I didn't presume that this tab selection is saved to the memory in the server and it is separated from the tab selection at main page. Moreover, the word "newest" is different than the word "active" at main page. That all were sum for my mistakes.